# Update data.frame in R

Tags: r

A data.frame "df"

```
   st1 st2 st3 st4 st5
1  0   0   0   0   0
2  0   0   0   0   0
3  0   0   0   0   0
4  0   0   0   0   0
5  0   0   0   0   0
6  0   0   0   0   0
```

is to be updated based on a vector. The vector is returned from some function call and every time, it may contain varying number of columns but the vector columns are always present in data.frame "df".

```
for (i in 1:10)
{
  x<-funcall()
  print(x)
  #           time.chosen
  #st3        2
  #st5        4
  // Update data.frame "df"
}
```

Is there any simple way to do this kind of update in R?

UPDATED:
Lets suppose, for 1st iteration of for loop, x is

```
           time.chosen
st3        2
st5        4
```

then the data.frame df should look like following

```
  st1 st2 st3 st4 st5
1  0   0   2   0   4
2  0   0   0   0   0
3  0   0   0   0   0
4  0   0   0   0   0
5  0   0   0   0   0
6  0   0   0   0   0
```

Each iteration of loop correspond to a row in data.frame df.

Comment: Does each iteration `i` in the `for` loop correspond to a row in the data frame? Could you provide an example of what you would like the updated data frame to look like based on the results you presented?

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you require? Do the columns pre - exist in the df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehing like this should work:

```
      df[iter,rownames(vector)] <- vector$time.chosen
```

Here I assume that vector is a data.frame like this :

Here an example :

```
vector = data.frame(time.chosen= c(1,2))
rownames(vector) <- paste('t',c(2,3),sep='')
  time.chosen
t2           1
t3           2

df <- as.data.frame(diag(5)*0)
colnames(df) <- paste('t',c(1:5),sep='')


iter <- 1
df[iter,rownames(vector)] <- vector$time.chosen

t1 t2 t3 t4 t5
1  0  1  2  0  0
2  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  0  0
5  0  0  0  0  0

 iter <-4
 df[iter,rownames(vector)] <- vector$time.chosen

 t1 t2 t3 t4 t5
1  0  1  2  0  0
2  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  1  2  0  0
5  0  0  0  0  0
```